# Reduce IME padding for child composable in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I have a screen with a NavigationBar and a content screen with a TextField as follow:

```
+-------------------------------+
|                               |
|      Content Composable       |
|                               |
|    _____________________      |
|   |                     |     |
|   |     TextField       |     |
|   |_____________________|     |
|                               |
|                               |
|                               |
+----------+----------+---------+
|   Home   |  Search  | Profile |
+----------+----------+---------+


Column {
    Column(Modifier.verticalScroll().weight(1f)) {
        ...
        TextField(...)
    }
    NavigationBar { ... }
}
```

If I apply `.imePadding()` modifier to the inner Column, the bottom padding would be too large as it doesn't compensate for the NavigationBar and bottom system bar. How do I subtract the height of the navigation bar and bottom system bar from this IME padding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WindowInsets subtraction can be done with `.consumeWindowInsets(PaddingValues(...))`.

I wrote the following modifier that adjusts the padding depending on how far composable is from the bottom of the window:

```
fun Modifier.positionAwareImePadding() = composed {
    var consumePadding by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }
    onGloballyPositioned { coordinates ->
        val rootCoordinate = coordinates.findRootCoordinates()
        val bottom = coordinates.positionInWindow().y + coordinates.size.height

        consumePadding = (rootCoordinate.size.height - bottom).toInt()
    }
        .consumeWindowInsets(PaddingValues(bottom = consumePadding.pxToDp()))
        .imePadding()
}
```

Example usage in OP's scenario:

```
Column {
    Column(modifier = Modifier
        .positionAwareImePadding()
        .verticalScroll()
        .weight(1f)
    ) {
        ...
        TextField(...)
    }
    NavigationBar { ... }
}
```

Comment: This is great, I'd possibly add the use of `LocalDensity.current` to properly convert the `Int` value of `consumePadding` into `Dp`.